# Reversing a number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a function to reverse a number in Ruby. IE, `314159.reverse` should return `951413`.

Here's what I have, which works:

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = self.to_s.reverse

    if self.is_a?(Float)
      return str.to_f
    elsif self.is_a?(Integer)
      return str.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

I don't like the enumeration of different number types. Is there a way to dynamically pass in the type?

Something like:

```
return str.to_type(self.type)
```

Any other thoughts on simplifying this?

**See also:** My related [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31127482/1445366) on some other approaches I tried.

Comment: What does it even mean to reverse a Float? An extra digit of precision would make a huge difference in the result.

Comment: @200_success For example, if `self` is `4042.840399100887`, it should return `788001993048.2404`. (Which my code does without precision issues.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to refactor this in small steps so that you can follow my thought process and see where you agree and you disagree.

First, let's start with some style. In Ruby, `self` is the implied receiver of a message send if you don't supply one, it is generally not necessary to state it explicitly:

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = to_s.reverse

    if is_a?(Float)
      return str.to_f
    elsif is_a?(Integer)
      return str.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Conditionals are expressions in Ruby, not statements. In fact, *everything* is an expression in Ruby. So, conditionals evaluate to a value, which means that instead of returning a value from each of the branches, we can return the value of the entire conditional expression instead:

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = to_s.reverse

    return if is_a?(Float)
      str.to_f
    elsif is_a?(Integer)
      str.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Being an expression-oriented language, the value of a method body (and also a block body, module body, class body, any block of code, really) is the value of the last expression evaluated inside that body. There is no need to explicitly `return` (or `next` in case of a block) it:

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = to_s.reverse

    if is_a?(Float)
      str.to_f
    elsif is_a?(Integer)
      str.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

For multi-way conditionals like this, it is usually more legible to use a `case` expression, instead of a series of `if` and `elsif`s:

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = to_s.reverse

    case
    when is_a?(Float)
      str.to_f
    when is_a?(Integer)
      str.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Now we can start doing some *real* interesting changes. `Module#===` checks whether its argument is an instance of `self`. `Object#is_a?` checks whether `self` is an instance of its argument. IOW: the two methods are mirror images of each other, you can usually exchange `o.is_a?(m)` with `m === o` and vice-versa. This allows us to simplify our `case` expression even more:

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = to_s.reverse

    case self
    when Float
      str.to_f
    when Integer
      str.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Now, on to the *big thing*!

In an object-oriented language, it is always possible to replace a conditional with runtime polymorphic message dispatch. Message dispatch is more powerful than conditionals. Smalltalk is the existence proof of that, it doesn't even *have* conditionals built into the language, its conditionals are implemented in the library, using message dispatch, kind of like this:

```
class TrueClass
  def if_then_else(then_block, else_block)
    then_block.()
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def if_then_else(then_block, else_block)
    else_block.()
  end
end

(2 > 3).if_then_else(-> { puts 'True' }, -> { puts 'False' })
# False
```

This gives rise to the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism Refactoring](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html). (Here is [an example of it in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924800/2988).)

In your case, you are not just switching behavior based on some abstract notion of "type" of the object, you are *literally* switching behavior based on the *class*. Even worse: you are switching based on the class of `self`.

That is a big honking red flag: `self` always knows what class it is. It should *never ever* have to check for its own class!

What you are basically doing is re-implementing message dispatch:

```
foo.bar
```

will run different code, depending on the class of `foo`. That's already built into Ruby, you don't have to re-implement it yourself.

So, we let Ruby take care of making the decision whether to invoke the `Float` or the `Integer` version of our code:

```
class Integer
  def reverse
    str = to_s.reverse

    str.to_i
  end
end

class Float
  def reverse
    str = to_s.reverse

    str.to_f
  end
end
```

Okay. So, the last bit we have here is a little bit of code duplication, which we can get rid of by using the [Extract Method Refactoring](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) followed by the [Pull Up Method Refactoring](http://refactoring.com/catalog/pullUpMethod.html).

Extract:

```
class Integer
  def reverse
    reverse_to_s.to_i
  end

  private def reverse_to_s
    to_s.reverse
  end
end

class Float
  def reverse
    reverse_to_s.to_f
  end

  private def reverse_to_s
    to_s.reverse
  end
end
```

Pull Up:

```
class Numeric
  private def reverse_to_s
    to_s.reverse
  end
end

class Integer
  def reverse
    reverse_to_s.to_i
  end
end

class Float
  def reverse
    reverse_to_s.to_f
  end
end
```

Now we're done. Our code is nice and clean, all our methods do exactly one thing, [there are no `IF`s](http://antiifcampaign.com/) or other conditionals.

The only slightly smelly bit left is the monkey-patching we are doing. [Refinements](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/syntax/refinements.rdoc) to the rescue!

```
module ReversibleNumeric
  refine Numeric do
    private def reverse_to_s
      to_s.reverse
    end
  end

  refine Integer do
    def reverse
      reverse_to_s.to_i
    end
  end

  refine Float do
    def reverse
      reverse_to_s.to_f
    end
  end
end

314159.reverse
# NoMethodError

using ReversibleNumeric

314159.reverse
# => 951413
```

[Well, actually, Refinements are still in a state of flux, and the above code may or may not work, depending on your exact version and implementation of Ruby.]

Answer (score 3):

How about using a case statement.

```
def reverse(n)
  as_string = n.to_s.reverse
  case n
  when Float
    Float(as_string)
  when Integer
    Integer(as_string)
  end
end

reverse(1234.5678) # => 8765.4321 A Float
reverse(12343) # => 34321 which is an Integer
reverse(832987979497908) # => 809794979789238 A Bignum
reverse(0371) # => 942 An Octal
reverse(0x1f) # => 13 A Hexadecimal
```

Comment: I like that this doesn't use `to_f`, etc. But is there a way to go a step further - something like `n.type(as_string)` - which would let me remove the `case` statement entirely?

Comment: You can, of course, choose not to use the case statement for another branch statement.  I think it would simply trade complexities.  Even your statement suggests that you are converting a number to a type from a string, which hints that you would get the same type as the object referred to as 'n', as the method name should reflect the return of the method.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the internals of a class is [usually frowned upon](http://devblog.avdi.org/2008/02/23/why-monkeypatching-is-destroying-ruby/), also, I feel like reversing a float is not going to be useful, so you can greatly simplify when caring only about integers:

```
def number_reverse(n)
  n.to_s.reverse.to_i
end

p number_reverse(12345) #-> 12345
```

Comment: Reversing a float is a requirement.

Comment: The article you linked to makes a good case for not overriding existing methods, but I'm not doing that here. Unless future versions of Ruby add a `reverse` method to `Numeric`, what's the harm?

Comment: @AaronBrager "What's the harm?" The harm is if everyone does the same. _Ruby_ might not add this or that method, but maybe someone else's code will ("what's the harm?" they said). Or maybe _you're_ overriding something that some other code added and relies on, and again things break. Hence the advice to just not do it. Otherwise you risk a slippery slope. Not saying it will happen, but if there's a another solution, why risk it? As you yourself implied, there's really no practical reason to add a `reverse` method to `Numeric`, so why would you do it?

Comment: @Flambino Ah, interesting. In Swift, such a conflict would cause a compile-time error, making it immediately apparent and easily diagnosable.

Comment: But back to my question - is there no way to generically convert the type without enumerating them?

Comment: @AaronBrager No (separate) compile step in Ruby. It's just a completely different beast. More flexibility, though - just act responsibly. E.g. `ActiveSupport` from Rails includes many additions to core stuff, but that its point. The presumption is that you use it with open eyes. And it strives to only add widely-applicable stuff with well-known behavior. Your `reverse` method is pretty narrow and its behavior isn't quite implicit (e.g. what _does_ it mean to reverse a float? Flipping some bits?) so be careful with mixins. It's OK to use for exercises or small isolated scripts, though.

Comment: In Ruby, you *will* get a warning "method redefined", though, provided you have warnings turned on. You *do* have warnings turned on during development and testing, don't you?